# parse variable rows XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a following response from a web service returning a list of products with details:

```
 <ResponseParameters>
        <Parameter name="productInfoproductID3" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoproductID2" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoproductID1" value="blaBlaBla"/><!-- variable number of rows-->
        <Parameter name="originTransactionID" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoStartDate3" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="availableServiceCapabilities" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoOfferType3" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoStartDate2" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="negotiatedCapabilities" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoOfferType2" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoStartDate1" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoOfferType1" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="responseCode" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoExpiryDate3" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoExpiryDate2" value="blaBlaBla"/>
        <Parameter name="productInfoExpiryDate1" value="blaBlaBla"/>
     </ResponseParameters>
```

Now this response can have any number of rows and in above response 1st product has detail `productInfoproductID1, productInfoStartDate1, productInfoExpiryDate1` and for 2nd I'd have `productInfoproductID2, productInfoStartDate2, productInfoExpiryDate2`.

How can I parse such an xml? Does JaxB supports anything for this case or I'd need to write a custom parser here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the XML example you have provided there is no reason why you can't just use the [Java's DOM Parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) (JDOM) to retrieve the Parameter Names and their respective Values (if you like). Here is an example with the XML you provided being read in from a text file:

Required Imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

try {
    File file = new File("xml.txt");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(file);
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("Parameter");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node namedItem = nList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
        Node valueItem = nList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value");
        System.out.printf("%-35s | %-1s", namedItem.getNodeName() + ": " + namedItem.getNodeValue(), 
                valueItem.getNodeName() + ": " + valueItem.getNodeValue() + System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to sort the data a specific way then place the extracted data into a Collection or Map instead of printing it to Console. If the above code is run then this is what is displayed within the Console Window:

```
name: productInfoproductID3         | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoproductID2         | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoproductID1         | value: blaBlaBla
name: originTransactionID           | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoStartDate3         | value: blaBlaBla
name: availableServiceCapabilities  | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoOfferType3         | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoStartDate2         | value: blaBlaBla
name: negotiatedCapabilities        | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoOfferType2         | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoStartDate1         | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoOfferType1         | value: blaBlaBla
name: responseCode                  | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoExpiryDate3        | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoExpiryDate2        | value: blaBlaBla
name: productInfoExpiryDate1        | value: blaBlaBla
```